# Mysql join on similar columns

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join table1 with table2 on column 'Name', but table2.Name has an 'e' in front of all the names (if table1.name=ABC,table2.name=eABC). How am I supposed to use a join for those two?
I tried `FROM table1 join table2 on 'e'+table1.name = table2.name`, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
JOIN    table2 t2
ON      t2.name = CONCAT('e', t1.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a substring of the table2 name.  So something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
     , table2
 WHERE table1.name = substring(table2.name, 1, length(table2.name))
```

I can't remember if substring is zero based, so just play with the numbers.